# Formar una expresión regular para hacer el remplazo de un dato en la lectura de un archivo PDF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, soapui

Hola muy buenas a todos.

soy nuevo en la comunidad.

tengo un programa que lee un archivo PDF y busca ciertas etiquetas en el archivo para hacer el remplazo de ellas y colocar los datos enviados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puede venir de muchas esa formas como están en el archivo

el código que utilizo en este momento para el remplazo es este:

public static PDDocument replaceTextPdf(PDDocument document, String searchString, String replacement) throws IOException {
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(searchString) || StringUtils.isEmpty(replacement)) {
return document;
}

```
    for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
        parser.parse();
        List<?> tokens = parser.getTokens();

        for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
            Object next = tokens.get(j);
            if (next instanceof Operator) {
                Operator op = (Operator) next;
                
                String pstring = "";
                int prej = 0;
                
                if (op.getName().equals("Tj")) {
                    COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    String string = previous.getString();
                    string = string.replaceFirst(searchString, replacement);
                    previous.setValue(string.getBytes());
                } else if (op.getName().equals("TJ")) {
                    COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                        Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                        if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                            COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                            String string = cosString.getString();
                            if (j == prej) {
                                pstring += string;
                            } else {
                                prej = j;
                                pstring = string;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                   
                    if (searchString.equals(pstring.replace(" ", ""))) {
                        COSString cosString2 = (COSString) previous.getObject(0);
                        cosString2.setValue(replacement.getBytes());
                        System.out.println(cosString2);
                        int total = previous.size() - 1;
                        for (int k = total; k > 0; k--) {
                            previous.remove(k);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(document);
        OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
        ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
        tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
        out.close();
        page.setContents(updatedStream);
    }
    return document;
}
```

para realizar el remplazo yo envio al servicio soap el nombre de la etiqueta por ejemplo:

InfoTitular_FechaNacimiento
13/02/2021

cuando intento realizar el remplazo de las palabras no encentra las etiquetas ya que imprimo la variable que extrae el texto del documento y me los trae de la siguiente manera o es lo que me muestra la consola del eclipse IDE:

: {TEXTO ;
InfoTitular_FechaNacimi
ento}

{TEXTO ;
InfoTitular_T
elefono}

{LISTA;Lista_Info
Titular_InfoCobert
ura_Capital}

{LISTA
;Lista_InfoTit
ular_InfoCob
ertura_Prima
Neta}

{LI
ST
A;

Li
st
a_
In
fo
Ti
tu
la
r_
In
fo
B
en
ef
ici
ar
io
_
Di
gi
to
}

intente eliminar los espacios y unir toda la cadena de las etiquetas pero no obtuve resultado.

muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo he intentado en múltiples ocasiones realiza ese tipo de funcionamiento, incluso he utilizado el código que muestras pero nunca lo he logrado hacer funcionar con archivos  PDF, lo único que logre fue tener campos editables y rellenarlos pero el usuario los puede editar también lo cual no es los que se busca, el enfoque que me funciono para el tiempo que tenia fue utilizar archivos de Word editarlos con ApachePOI y convertirlos a PDF, porque las librerías que me funcionaron para editar pdf todas son de pago como aspose y su precio inicia en 3000 dólares.